# BSPWM not starting from the display manager

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, window-manager, display-manager

I'm using Ubuntu with Gnome, when i go to the display manager, choose bspwm and type my password then hit enter the screen freezes and bspwm doesn't launch.

Here's my bspwmrc file even though I don't think the problem is here:

```
#! /bin/sh

pgrep -x sxhkd > /dev/null || sxhkd &

#setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle fr,us,ar &

picom &

feh --bg-fill $HOME/Downloads/Wallpapers/pink1.jpg


killall -q polybar

polybar -c ~/.config/polybar/config.ini main -r &

bspc monitor -d I II III IV V VI VII 

xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr &
picom --experimental-backends &

#bspc config focus_follows_pointer true

 
bspc config border_width    2
bspc config window_gap          4
bspc config split_ratio          0.5
bspc config borderless_monocle   true
bspc config gapless_monocle      true


#border colors
bspc config focused_border_color   "#F4ACB7"
bspc config normal_border_color "#454849"

bspc rule -a Gimp desktop='^8' state=floating follow=on
bspc rule -a Chromium desktop='^2'
bspc rule -a mplayer2 state=floating
bspc rule -a Kupfer.py focus=on
bspc rule -a Screenkey manage=off
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out! Here's how I fixed it:

- chmod +x both  bspwmrc and sxhkdrc
- copy bspwm.desktop to the xsessions folder with:

  sudo cp (folder where bspwm is installed)/contrib/freedesktop/bspwm.desktop /usr/share/xsessions/